# Remove <li> from to do list?

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists

how would I remove a list item from my to do list onclick! And how would i set up a counter to add and display how many tasks i have and how many left once one is deleted.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Task 1</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css">
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <h1>My To Do List</h1>
    <input type="text" id="input_field" name="input_field" placeholder="Enter New Task" required>
    <button type="button" id="add" onclick="addtask()" > Add Task</button>
</div>
<ul id="todo_list"></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function addtask() {
var input = document.getElementById('input_field').value;
    if (input == "") {
        window.alert("You must enter a value in the New Task field.");
    }
    else {
        var noteList = document.getElementById('todo_list');
        noteList.innerHTML += "<li>" + input + "<button id='delete'>clear</button></li>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at http://todomvc.com/, they have a vanilla js implementation as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an `onclick` event to clear button and call the function `clearItem()` that deletes the item.

For your second question,

> And how would i set up a counter to add and display how many tasks i
>   have and how many left once one is deleted.

Add a variable `total_added` that increment when the user adds an item, and another variable `remaining` that `decrement` when the user clears an item.

```js
var total_added = 0;  //initialize the var to zero
var remaining = 0;    //initialize the var to zero

function addtask() {
  var input = document.getElementById('input_field').value;
  if (input == "") {
    window.alert("You must enter a value in the New Task field.");
  }
  else {
    var noteList = document.getElementById('todo_list');
    noteList.innerHTML += "<li>" + input + "<button id='delete' onclick='clearItem()'>clear</button></li>";
    
    total_added++;
    remaining++;    //increment total_added and remaining when user adds an item
    
    document.getElementById('total_added').innerHTML = "Total number of tasks added = " + total_added;
    
  document.getElementById('remaining').innerHTML = "Number of tasks remaining = " + remaining;
  }
}

function clearItem() {
  event.currentTarget.parentElement.remove();
  
  remaining--;  //decrement remaining when user clears an item
  
  document.getElementById('remaining').innerHTML = "Number of tasks remaining = " + remaining;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Task 1</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css">
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <h1>My To Do List</h1>
    <input type="text" id="input_field" name="input_field" placeholder="Enter New Task" required>
    <button type="button" id="add" onclick="addtask()" > Add Task</button>
</div>
<ul id="todo_list"></ul>
  <p id="total_added">Total number of tasks added = 0</p>
  <p id="remaining">Number of tasks remaining = 0</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot, but is there any other way to delete an item, rather using "event.currentTarget.parentElement.remove();"? what if it was output to the div rather than li. thanks

Comment: `event.currentTarget.parentElement.remove();` removes the parent tag in which the button exist, whether it is `li` or `div`

Comment: ok. sorry for another question, what if I didnt have a button and wanted to remove item by clicking on it, in innerhtml

Comment: Add  `onclick='clearItem()'` to `<li>` instead of button. And change `event.currentTarget.parentElement.remove();` to `event.currentTarget.remove();` since you are removing the same element (ie, `<li>`) that you clicked.

Comment: thanks, one last one, what if instead of removing item i wanted to make it look crossed out

Comment: Actually what you needed ? To delete or to cross out ?

Comment: I needed either, I am just practising thats, why wanted to know more than one way of removing the item :) thanks a lot for ur help

Comment: To have a strike through text, use css `text-decoration: line-through;`. And to set it using javascript use `event.currentTarget.style.textDecoration = "line-through";` instead of deleting

Answer (score 0):

Add the removeTask() function in the onClick event of the delete button and add the removeTask function.

Like this :

JS :

```
function addtask() {
  var input = document.getElementById('input_field').value;
  if (input == "") {
    window.alert("You must enter a value in the New Task field.");
  } else {
    var noteList = document.getElementById('todo_list');
    noteList.innerHTML += "<li>" + input + "<button id='delete'  onclick='removeTask()' >clear</button></li>";
    countItems();

  }
}

function removeTask() {
  event.currentTarget.parentElement.remove();
  countItems();
}

function countItems() {
  var count = document.querySelectorAll("#todo_list > li").length;
  document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = count + ' item(s)';

}
```

HTML :

```
  <div id="container">
    <h1 id="title">My To Do List</h1>
    <p id="count"></p>
    <input type="text" id="input_field" name="input_field" placeholder="Enter New Task" required>
    <button type="button" id="add" onclick="addtask()"> Add Task</button>
  </div>
  <ul id="todo_list"></ul>
```

## [CodePen](http://codepen.io/bugyt/pen/yOVvRb)

Answer (score 0):

I think counter of the list is unnecessary. You could always count `childNode` in your `todo_list` for the left todo list. But counter for deleted list is still useful.

```
var list_now = document.getElementById('todo_list').childNodes.length;
```